# Multiple Constructors with no default parameter value for some parameters

Tags: java, constructor

In case you need to create multiple constructors, the straight forward solution will be to chain the constructors. One constructor calls to another with some default value.
But what if there isn't a default value?

For example a class with below three constructors:

```
public MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) // constructor 1
{

    if (person== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
    }
    if (enum1== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
    }       

    this.person= person;
    this.enum1 = enum1;     
}

public MyClass(Person person)  // constructor 2
{

    if (person== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
    }   

    this.person= person;    
}

public MyClass(SomeEnum enum1)  // constructor 3
{

    if (enum1== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
    }       

    this.enum1 = enum1;     
}
```

I don't want to validate the same fields in multiple constructors and so I'll try to make *constructors 2* and *3* call to *constructor 1*:

```
public MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) // constructor 1
    {

        if (person== null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
        }
        if (enum1== null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
        }       

        this.person= person;
        this.enum1 = enum1;     
    }

    public MyClass(Person person)  // constructor 2
    {                   
        this(prerson, SomeEnum.NO_VALUE);
    }

    public MyClass(SomeEnum enum1)  // constructor 3
    {               
        this(?, enum1);
    }
```

So let's say we have some default value in **SomeEnum**, but what with *constructor 3*, I don't have a default value for **Person**.
I can change the call chain and make constructors 1 and 2 call to constructor 3, and then validate and set Person by themselves, but I don't want Person validation to be in two places.

I also don't like the idea to create some **NotPerson** object that extends **Person** and use it.
And the builder pattern is also something not right for me.
Also, the validation can be more complex than just check for null.

Comment: Extract the validation into a method?

Comment: In your first example constructor 2, what should be the state of the field `enum1` after construction? Null? Likewise, first example constructor 3, what should be the state of the field `person`?

Comment: If both parameters have to be provided, neither of the single-argument constructors can possibly be legal, unless there is a sensible default for both of them, which you haven't mentioned. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `this(null, enum1);` ?

Comment: I don't think the validations should be different c'tors (the validation logic I mean, not the methods), and therefor - in the third c'tor you should not leave person as null, as it's invalid per the first c'tor. The question is simple - what is the default value for person- if it's null, don't fail on the first, if it's something else - use it in the third. once you sort this out, using the first c'tor (or builder) is clearer

Comment: @Michael When using constructor with Person parameter than the enum parameter will be null, the opposite for constructor 3.

Comment: @user207421 who said that both parameters must be provided?
They must be provided only in the first constructor, in the other constructors only the signature parameter must not be null.

Comment: @Eritrean this will fail on IllegalArgumentException in the first constructor

Comment: @user3132197 Your 2-argument constructor says so. If those aren't the real semantics, why did you write it that way?

Comment: @user207421 is is correct that when using the 2-argument constructor, than both the parameters should NOT be null.

Comment: So how can the single-argument constructors possibly be legal? You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is mainly with the duplication of the checks then [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) can easily address this. It will generate the equivalent code automatically. It uses NullPointerException by default but it is configurable to use IllegalArgumentException if you want.

```
public MyClass(@NonNull Person person, @NonNull SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.person = person;
    this.enum1 = enum1;     
}

public MyClass(@NonNull Person person) {
    this.person = person;    
}

public MyClass(@NonNull SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.enum1 = enum1;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write private static validation methods. A compact way to use them would look like this:

```
public MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.person = validatePerson(person);
    this.enum1 = validateSomeEnum(enum1);
}
public MyClass(Person person) {
    this.person = validatePerson(person);
}
public MyClass(SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.enum1 = validateSomeEnum(enum1);
}

private static Person validatePerson(Person person) {
    if (person == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
    }
    return person;
}
private static SomeEnum validateSomeEnum(SomeEnum enum1) {
    if (enum1 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
    }
    return enum1;
}
```

*Uses*

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(person, enum1);
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(person);
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(enum1);
```

---

You can also do it with static construction methods, useful to help clarify the arguments if there is ambiguity, by naming the static method differently:

```
public static MyClass of(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) {
    validatePerson(person);
    validateSomeEnum(enum1);
    return new MyClass(person, enum1);
}
public static MyClass of(Person person) {
    validatePerson(person);
    return new MyClass(person, null);
}
public static MyClass of(SomeEnum enum1) {
    validateSomeEnum(enum1);
    return new MyClass(null, enum1);
}

private static void validatePerson(Person person) {
    if (person == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
    }
}
private static void validateSomeEnum(SomeEnum enum1) {
    if (enum1 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
    }
}

private MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.person = person;
    this.enum1 = enum1;
}
```

*Uses*

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.of(person, enum1);
MyClass myClass = MyClass.of(person);
MyClass myClass = MyClass.of(enum1);
```

---

Another option is the Builder Pattern, especially useful if there are many optional properties:

```
public static final class Builder {
    private Person person;
    private SomeEnum enum1;

    public Builder withPerson(Person person) {
        if (person == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
        }
        this.person = person;
        return this;
    }
    public Builder withSomeEnum(SomeEnum enum1) {
        if (enum1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
        }
        this.enum1 = enum1;
        return this;
    }
    public MyClass create() {
        if (this.person == null && this.enum1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One of person or enum1 is required.");
        }
        return new MyClass(this.person, this.enum1);
    }
}

private MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) {
    this.person = person;
    this.enum1 = enum1;
}
```

*Uses*

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder()
        .withPerson(person)
        .withSomeEnum(enum1)
        .create();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder()
        .withPerson(person)
        .create();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder()
        .withSomeEnum(enum1)
        .create();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first solution is the best between the three, because in my case I have many classes that extend MyClass and than using super to call to different MyClass's constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to rearrange the the chain call better:

```
public MyClass(Person person, SomeEnum enum1) // constructor 1
{

    this(enum1);
    if (person== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null.");
    }   

    this.person= person;   
}

public MyClass(Person person)  // constructor 2
{
    this(person, SomeEnum.NoValue);     
}

public MyClass(SomeEnum enum1)  // constructor 3
{

    if (enum1== null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("enum1 cannot be null.");
    }       

    this.enum1 = enum1;     
}
```